# Align figures to the left side of an article

Tags: floats, captions, marginpar

I am trying to write a user manual for a product for which I would like to have several figures and small explanatory test in a column to the left of each page. I have run into a strange issue, where I have not been able to do that. Here's the non working MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

    \blindtext

    \marginnote[left]{this is just a test1}[-3 cm]

    \marginpar{
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{filename}
    \captionof{figure}{Text of the caption}
}

\end{document}
```

There are multiple issues that I am facing:

1. I would like the figures and text to the left of the main body text, not on the right.
2. The marginnote does not render at all in the example above.

---

ETA: The below seems to work for me for now.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5 in, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=130pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\reversemarginpar
\begin{document}

    \marginnote{this is just a test1. this is just a test1. }[3 cm]

    \begin{marginfigure}[12 cm]
        \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{demo}
        \caption{test image}
    \end{marginfigure}

    \blinddocument

\end{document}
```

The question is, is this the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\reversemarginpar` and

```
    \marginnote{this is just a test1}[-3 cm]
    \marginnote{
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{filename}
    \captionof{figure}{Text of the caption}
}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{caption}
\reversemarginpar
\begin{document}
        \blindtext
    \marginnote{this is just a test1}[-3 cm]
    \marginnote{
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{filename}
    \captionof{figure}{Text of the caption}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As far as your edit regarding `sidenotes` is concerned, it is perfectly al right to use it.

Comment: Thanks. What is the purpose of using the caption package and corresponding \captionof in this case?

Comment: @VaibhavGarg You don't want your margin figures to float is it not? That is why. :-)

Comment: You are right, I don't.